# Using Christoffel symbols to derive formulas for div, grad, curl

Tags: differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, differentiation

In Sean Carroll's GR book, pg. 1oo, it was said that in flat space, the Christoffel symbols vanish in Cartesian coordinates. However, in curvilinear coordinates, they do not vanish. For example, for plane polar coordinates

$$ds^2=dr^2+r^2 d\theta^2$$

the Christoffel symbols are
$$\Gamma^r_{rr}=\Gamma^r_{r\theta}=\Gamma^{\theta}_{rr}=\Gamma^\theta_{\theta\theta}=0$$
$$\Gamma^r_{\theta\theta}=-r$$
$$\Gamma^\theta_{r\theta}=\frac{1}{r}$$

The author then said that using these and similar expressions, we can derive formulas for the div, grad and curl in curilinear coordinate systems. How exactly is it done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an arbitrary coordinate system on a manifold, the grad, div and curl are defined using covariant derivatives:

$$\nabla\phi=(\nabla_a\phi)\textbf{e}^a$$
$$\nabla \cdot \textbf{v}=\nabla_av^a$$
$$(\text{curl} \textbf{v})_{ab}= \nabla_av_b -\nabla_bv_a$$
where $\phi$ is a scalar field, $\textbf{v}$ is a vector field and $(\text{curl} \textbf{v})_{ab}$ is a rank 2 tensor.

Since covariant derivatives of tensors $\phi$ and $v^a$ can be expressed using partial derivatives and Christoffel symbols, i.e.
$$\nabla_a\phi=\partial_a\phi$$
$$\nabla_a v^a= \partial_av^a +{\Gamma^a}_{ca}v^c$$
we say that the formulas for grad, div and curl  in an arbitrary coordinate system can be derived using  Chirstoffel symbols.

Comment: o_o, I think there is an error in $\nabla_a v^a $ equation